# Reflect Geometric Node around arbitrary axis in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, geometry

Is there a way in javafx to reflect/mirror a geometric node (line for example) around an arbitrary axis-- one that is user-defined?

I see rotation, scale, shear, and translation methods, but no reflect(mirror).

I stumpled upon a post that suggests using alignment Left to right , or Right to left, but it is not quit what I am looking for.

I didn't build the application yet to post sample code, as I am still looking for quite a few libraries before starting.

Any tips would be great from the community!

EDIT: Not sure how to add images to comments. I tried the code by James below, I get the result in the image below, but I am trying to get it where noted in read.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a line segment defined by two points `p1` and `p2`, then reflecting in that line segment is equivalent to

1. Translate `p1` to the origin (`T`)
2. Rotate `p2` to the positive x-axis (`R`)
3. Reflect in the x-axis (which you can do with a scale with `x=1` and `y=-1`)
4. Inverse of `R`
5. Inverse of `T`

So this looks something like

```
private Transform createReflection(Point2D p1, Point2D p2) {
    Translate translation = new Translate(-p1.getX(), -p1.getY());
    double deltaX = p2.getX() - p1.getX();
    double deltaY = p2.getY() - p1.getY();
    Rotate rotate = new Rotate(-Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX)));
    Scale scale = new Scale(1, -1);
    Affine reflection = new Affine();
    reflection.append(translation.createInverse());
    try {
        // not sure how a rotation could possibly be non-invertible:
        reflection.append(rotate.createInverse());
    } catch (NonInvertibleTransformException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    reflection.append(scale);
    reflection.append(rotate);
    reflection.append(translation);
    return reflection ;
}
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.transform.Affine;
import javafx.scene.transform.NonInvertibleTransformException;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.scene.transform.Transform;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ArbitraryReflection extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Text original = new Text("Through the looking glass");
        original.relocate(200,  350);

        Text reflected = new Text("Through the looking glass");
        reflected.relocate(200, 350);

        Group reflectedGp = new Group(reflected);


        Point2D start = new Point2D(0, 400);
        Point2D end = new Point2D(400, 150);
        Line axis = new Line(start.getX(), start.getY(), end.getX(), end.getY());
        Pane root = new Pane(original, reflectedGp, axis);
        reflectedGp.getTransforms().add(createReflection(start, end));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();



    }

    private Transform createReflection(Point2D p1, Point2D p2) {
        Translate translation = new Translate(-p1.getX(), -p1.getY());
        double deltaX = p2.getX() - p1.getX();
        double deltaY = p2.getY() - p1.getY();
        Rotate rotate = new Rotate(-Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX)));
        Scale scale = new Scale(1, -1);
        Affine reflection = new Affine();
        reflection.append(translation.createInverse());
        try {
            // not sure how a rotation could possibly be non-invertible:
            reflection.append(rotate.createInverse());
        } catch (NonInvertibleTransformException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        reflection.append(scale);
        reflection.append(rotate);
        reflection.append(translation);
        return reflection ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi James, Thanks. Almost there. I updated the question with an image showing the result the code posted. (not sure how to add images to comments). The result I am looking for is highlighted in red in the image above. Any tips?

Comment: Well, that's not the result of the code I posted, which reflects in a line through `(0 , 400)` and `(400, 150)`. So I can't really tell what's wrong in your version.

Comment: Hi James, Now works. I thought I only had changed the position of the line. Reset it to your original code, and change line start and end points again. Works fine now! Thanks :)